# sqlite - unable to query web db with WHERE clause

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I'm using the WHERE clause while trying to query my sqlite database. I know there is data in the db which I should be able to retrieve based on the conditionals in my query, but I can't seem to get it to work.

When I query without conditionals...

```
sql = 'select LocationGUID, ID, Fullname FROM tblUser';
```

I'm able to return all the data from the selected columns. Is this is a quotation issue? I've tried single and double-quotes around the conditional values but the number of rows I return is still 0.

Javascript:

```
sql = 'select LocationGUID, ID, Fullname FROM tblUser WHERE UserName=\'mike\' AND Password=\'mike123\'';

mydb = getDBConn();
mydb.transaction(function(tx) {tx.executeSql(sql, [], function(tx,results) {
var size = results.rows.length;

console.log(size);

for (var i=0;i<size;i++) {
    for (var key in results.rows.item(0)){
         var row = results.rows.item(i);
         console.log(row[key]);
    }
}
```

SQLite DB

[image]

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT UserName, typeof(UserName), hex(UserName) FROM tblUser` for this row?

Comment: mike                 
text 
6D696B6520202020202020202020202020202020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct query to find this row would be this:

```
SELECT ... FROM tblUser WHERE UserName = 'mike                ' AND ...
```

You might want to change the code that stores the data to remove these unwanted spaces.

To fix the database, use something like this:

```
UPDATE tblUser SET UserName = rtrim(UserName)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! I tried double-clicking the UserName and Password values to see if there were any empty spaces but nothing was hi-lighted in blue. The SELECT hex() query works great and I will have to remember it.